# PHP Login - Ending into redirect loop in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php

I have Login Page that accepts Email and Password to login. When i press Login then only in `Chrome` browser i am getting error like "Webpage has redirect Loop". Below is the code for JS:

```
function submitform(){
var email = $("#email").val();var password = $("#password").val();
var leaveblank = $("#leaveblank").val();var dontchange = $("#dontchange").val();
var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password + 
'&leaveblank=' + leaveblank+ '&dontchange=' + dontchange;
$("#loading").show();
 $.ajax({
    url: "includes/login_submit",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msg) {
      if (msg == 1) {
         $("#loading").hide();
        window.location.reload();
       } else {
         $("#loading").hide();
         $("#messagesuccerr").html("<span style=color:red;font-size:14px>Oops!! 
          Wrong Credentials!!</span>").fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
        return false;
        }
    }
});
```

}

Code for `login_submit`

```
$query = "select * from `register_userfm` where `emailfm` = ? and 
passwordfmenc = ?; ";
$resultfm1 = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute
(array($newlogemail,$hashedPWfm))->fetchAll();
    if(count($resultfm1)>0){
        foreach($resultfm1 as $rowrest1){
        $_SESSION['authuser_fmd'] = $rowrest1['name'];
}
```

Finally, the code on Login.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
}
//----- Auth Block -----------//
if(isset($_SESSION['authuser_fmd'])){
  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $_SESSION['loginurlref'] = $referrer;
  $urirediref = $_SESSION['loginurlref'];
  header('location: '.$urirediref.'');
}
//--------Auth Block Ends ------------//

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  $_SESSION['loginurlref'] = "http://example.com";
  header('location: '.$_SESSION['loginurlref'].'');
}
```

Now, when user click on Sign in then i get error like `This webpage has redirect loop`.  i tried removing auth block and the error was gone. But i have to redirect user back to page from where he lands on Sign in page.

Comment: when Ajax is used header redirect should not be used, as original page page is never redirected

Comment: so then how should i redirect to desired page. pl post a solution

Comment: use ob_start() at top and check

Comment: ob_start() at start don't help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax this might help

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/login_submit",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msg) {
      if (msg == 1) {
         $("#loading").hide();
        window.location.assign('your redirect page');
       } else {
         $("#loading").hide();
         $("#messagesuccerr").html("<span style=color:red;font-size:14px>Oops!! 
          Wrong Credentials!!</span>").fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
        return false;
        }
    }
});
```

and remove all redirects from login_submit.php

OR

you can use normal submit without AJAX

Comment: but how will i check if usr has came from refrrer URL or not

Comment: you check that in php code and return appropriate value as response which can be used in AJAX